# Understanding --readable_model and --invert_hash in vowpal wabbit for Neural Networks

Tags: hash, neural-network, vowpalwabbit

I was trying to make a diagram of the weights that vowpal wabbit has learnt to understand the architecture better and got very confused as to what was happening. I couldn't understand where all the weights given out by vowpal wabbit go in the structure.

My data:

```
$ cat dat1.vw 
1 | a b
2 | a c
```

When doing a neural network with 2 nodes:

```
vw --nn 2 --invert_hash dat.nn2.ih --readable_model dat.nn2.rm dat1.vw
```

it gives dat.nn2.ih and dat.nn2.rm with some information like max, min, checksum etc and the weights as:

From dat.nn2.ih (from --invert_hash):

```
:29015:-0.3161
Constant:202096:-0.270493
Constant[1]:202097:0.214776
[1]:29016:-0.302343
[2]:156909:-0.479347
a:108232:-0.270493
a[1]:108233:0.214776
b:129036:-0.0849519
b[1]:129037:0.0473027
c:219516:-0.196927
c[1]:219517:0.172029
```

And from dat.nn2.rm (--readable_model):

```
29015:-0.3161               # <blank> ?
29016:-0.302343             # [1] ?
108232:-0.270493            # a (from input "a" to hidden node 0)
108233:0.214776             # a[1] (from input "a" to hidden node 1)
129036:-0.0849519           # b (from input "b" to hidden node 0)
129037:0.0473027            # b[1] (from input "b" to hidden node 1)
156909:-0.479347            # [2] ?
156910:0.394566             # <nonexistent> not there in .ih file ?
156911:0.69414              # <nonexistent> not there in .ih file ?
202096:-0.270493            # Constant (bias for hidden node 0)
202097:0.214776             # Constant[1] (bias for hidden node 1)
219516:-0.196927            # c (from input "c" to hidden node 0)
219517:0.172029             # c[1] (from input "c" to hidden node 1)
```

So, I can understand a, a[1], b, b[1], c, c[1], Constant, Constant[1] but I am unable to figure out what the rest of the hashes are for ?

From my understanding, there should be 3 more weights/hashes:
 - From hidden node 0 to output node
 - From hidden node 1 to output node
 - Bias for output node

But I see a `<blank>`, `[1]`, `[2]` and 2 hashes which are in the .rm but not in .ih. What exactly do these weights represent ?